# I would like to know what the topics are involved in this question.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I would like to know what the topics are involved in this question that I can use to solve it. I have tried searching for exponents with variables or using functions although I can't find a way to start on this question.

> If $3^{m+1} = 5^{n-1} = 15^k$, show that $k(m+n) = (m+1)(n-1)$

*Thank you.*

Comment: @Sahiba I disagree with your edit. The exponent is "(m+1)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exponent rules.

Hint: Show that $ 15 ^ { k (m+n) } = 15 ^ { (m+1) (n-1)} $.

> Further hint: $ 15 ^ {k (n-1)} = 3^{(m+1)(n-1) }$.
>  Write a similar equation for $ 5^ { (m+1)(n-1)}$.

---

Complete details:

By raising the given equation to the $n-1$ power, we get
$ 15 ^ {k (n-1)} = 3^{(m+1)(n-1) }$.

> By raising the given equation to the $m+1$ power, we get
>  $15^{k(m+1) }  = 5 ^ { (m+1) (n-1) } $

$ $

> Multiplying these 2 identities, we get
>  $15^{ k ( n - 1 + m + 1 ) } = 3^{(m+1)(n-1) } \times 5 ^ { (m+1) (n-1) } $

which simplifies to
$15^{ k ( n +m ) } = 15^{(m+1)(n-1) }$.
Hence $ k (n+m) = (m+1)(n-1)$

Comment: Hello Calvin, would this question be able to be solved by log or indices? I have tried just using exponent rules but I got very confused. Also in your further hint, may I know why it seems that the right side is divided by 5 but the left side is still at 15? I was taught that both sides must be divided by the same number. If it is possible can you show me the working for the further hint equation? Thank you Calvin, appreciate it!

Comment: @Drake I've included the details.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask in a comment for a solution using $\log$:

Taking logarithms and noting that $\log 15 = \log 3 + \log 5$, you get two equations:

\begin{eqnarray*}
(m+1)\log 3 & = & k\log 3 + k \log 5 \\
(n-1)\log 5 & = & k\log 3 + k \log 5
\end{eqnarray*}

or equivalently, considering the cases $k= 0$ and $n-1-k=0$ separately,

$$\frac{\log 5}{\log 3} = \frac{m+1-k}{k} = \frac{k}{n-1-k}$$

Hence,

$$(m+1-k)(n-1-k)=k^2 \Leftrightarrow (m+1)(n-1)=k(m+n)$$

The case $k=0$ is easily directly verified to be true. The case $n-1=k$ falls with look at $5^{n-1}=15^k$ also back to the case $k=0$.

Comment: You don't have to worry about $ n - 1 - k = 0 $ or $ k = 0 $ because the LHS is well defined. (But thanks for ensuring that we didn't divide by 0.)